# AWS Lambda function for a website's view counter increments by 2 instead of 1

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I created a Lambda function that connects to my DynamoDB table and gets the item `view_count` and then sets `view_count += 1` and then updates the `view_count` item and returns `view_count` as a string.

When I open the Function URL the first time, it increments `view_count` by 1 and outputs 1 which is what I want. But whenever I refresh the page (to simulate another visitor to the website) **it always adds 2 more to `view_count` instead of 1 more**. The item in the table also always shows one more than what is displayed in the function URL.

My Lambda code:

```py
import boto3
import json
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Connect to DynamoDB
    dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
    table = dynamodb.Table("Table-CRC")

    # Get the current view count
    response = table.get_item(Key={"id": "1"})
    item = response.get("Item", {})
    view_count = item.get("view_count", 0)

    # Increment the view count
    view_count += 1

    # Update the view count in DynamoDB
    table.put_item(Item={"id": "1", "view_count": view_count})
  
   # Return the updated view count
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": str(view_count),
        "headers": {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }
```

Original setting of the item:

[image: Original setting of the item:]

First load of the URL:

[image: First load of the URL:]

What the item changed to:

[image: What the item changed to:]

Second load of the URL (hitting refresh):

[image: Second load of the URL (hitting refresh):]

What the item changed to after that:

[image: What the item changed to after that:]

I tried putting the `view_count` in the `table.get_item` Key statement and removing the two lines under it but that led to an Internal Server Error when I tried to access the Function URL so I think that's bad code.

Comment: It sounds like your function might be invoked more often than you expect. If you look in CloudWatch Logs, does it show more invocations than you expect.

Comment: FYI, you can [use Atomic Counters in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItems.html#WorkingWithItems.AtomicCounters) where you can tell DynamoDB to increment a field by a given value without first retrieving the current value. This works well in highly-parallel environments where a counter might be updated by multiple processes simultaneously. It also reduces the number of calls you need to make to DynamoDB. It won't fix your problem, but it's pretty neat!

Answer (score 1):

Your actually not updating anything, you are overwriting the item everytime by using `put_item`. You want to use `update_item` which will ensure no issue with race conditions.

```
import boto3
import json
# Connect to DynamoDB
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = dynamodb.Table("Table-CRC")
def lambda_handler(event, context):

   res = table.update_item(
        Key={"Id": "1"},
        UpdateExpression="SET view_count = view_count + :val",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':val': 1},
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
  
   # Return the updated view count
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": str(res['Item']['view_count']),
        "headers": {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    }
```

Some things to note about the code:

We no longer need to do `get_item` as DynamoDB can increment a number for us, this helps us avoid concurrency issues. We don't set any conditions in our update, as I assume over/under counting can be tolerated for your use-case where your counting webpage hits.

We use DynamoDB `update_item` which updates the item and not overwrites it, which again can help any concurrency issues. We return the new values, which returns the item after the update completed so you can return the current value accurately to your client.

We moved the DynamoDB initialization outside of the Lambda handler which will improve performance of your Lambda and can also reduce costs for KMS if you use encryption keys.

Comment: Ah I see, I wasn't updating it the right way by using put_item. I copied that code and got "Internal Server Error" (The only difference is that I changed Id from your code to id)

Comment: Internal server error from Lambda usually means something is wrong with your response, or you have an unhandled exception. I didn't test my code, I simply wrote it in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this code:

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resouce('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('Table-CRC')

response = table.update_item(Key={ "id":"1"}, 
                  UpdateExpression='SET view_count = view_count + :incr', 
                  ExpressionAttributeValues={':incr': {"N": "1"}} 
                  )
return response
```

Answer (score -1):

In your solution you will get problems with parallel requests as they may be written concurrently to the dynamodb resulting in not increased counters. You should use an update operation to atomically update the entry using dynamodb.

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table("Table-CRC")

try:
    response = table.update_item(
        Key={partition_key: partition_value, sort_key: sort_value}, # Key={id: "1"}
        UpdateExpression="SET view_count = view_count + :val",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':val': 1},
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
    print("Increment succeeded.")
except ClientError as e:
    print("Error:", e.response['Error']['Message'])
```

Comment: I copied that code and got "Internal Server Error"

Comment: in german we say "wer kopiert, verliert"